# Making SMS ViewController pop up on iPhone using Unity3D

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, unity-game-engine, sms

I am having trouble getting [`MFMessageCompose`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/index.html) to work with [Unity3D iOS Plugin](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html).

I got an alert window to pop up with buttons but I am having an error when accessing the `MFMessageComposer`.  Can't seem to get the method to pop up the window properly.

Here is my [`iOSBridge.h`](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qmcv7pwkduufvbx/iOSBridge.h?dl=0) (linked file if you want):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

@interface Delegate : NSObject <UINavigationControllerDelegate, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate>

@end
```

And my [iOSBridge.mm](https://www.dropbox.com/s/003iogk1hxgvc1e/iOSBridge.mm?dl=0) file:

```
#import "iOSBridge.h"

@implementation Delegate


//Trying to still understand the meaning behind this line.  Why???
-(id)init
{
    return self;
}

//RATE US Button Numbers
//Not entirely sure What I did here but it still bring it up.  This section has nothing to do with SMS
-(void) alertView: (UIAlertView*)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    //Give back the number of the button

    NSString *inStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)buttonIndex];
    const char *cString = [inStr cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    UnitySendMessage("Popup", "UserFeedBack", cString);
    NSLog(@"%li", (long)buttonIndex);
} // RATE US button number end

-(void)SMS:(id)sender{

    MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [controller setMessageComposeDelegate:self];

    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]){

        [controller setRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:nil]];
        [controller setBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Text"]];

        //WHYYY do you not work
        //[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES];

        Delegate *appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate;
        [appDelegate.window.rootViewController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil]
    }

}

@end

static Delegate* delegateObject;

extern "C"
{

//A method for unity can run
void _AddNotification(const char* title,
                  const char* body,
                  const char* cancelLabel,
                  const char* firstLabel,
                  const char* secondLabel)

{

//Don't have a full grasp of this delegateObject thing yet.
if(delegateObject ==nil){
    delegateObject = [[Delegate alloc]init];
}

//iOS Alert Pop up view RATE OUR GAME

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle: [NSString stringWithUTF8String:title]
                      message:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:body] delegate:delegateObject
                      cancelButtonTitle:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:cancelLabel]
                      otherButtonTitles:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:firstLabel],[NSString stringWithUTF8String:secondLabel], nil];


    [alert show];
} //End of _AddNotification


//SMS Method for Unity to use
void _SMSGO(const char* Mbody){

        MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
        if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]){

            NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", Mbody];
            controller.body = s;

            //Suppose to Brings up the SMS view not sure why it isnt working or how to make this work
            //If this can work its major progress

            [delegateObject presentViewController:controller animated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So these:

```
-(void) alertView: (UIAlertView*)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *inStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)buttonIndex];
    const char *cString = [inStr cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    UnitySendMessage("Popup", "UserFeedBack", cString);
    NSLog(@"%li", (long)buttonIndex);
}

-(void)SMS:(id)sender{

    MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [controller setMessageComposeDelegate:self];

    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]){

        [controller setRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:nil]];
        [controller setBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Text"]];

        //WHYYY do you not work
        //[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES];

        Delegate *appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate;
        [appDelegate.window.rootViewController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil]
    }    
}
```

Code blocks are actually not being accessed at all through your bridge. So nothing in this will be touched at all.

The `- (id) init` is the initializer of the class. So in order to access anything in that file from anything else, you have to `init` it first. An easier way to think of this is:

`extern.c` is a separate file.

```
static Delegate *delObj;

extern "C"
{
    void _callMain (const char *hello) {
        /**
         * delObj is a static so it "Will be once it is" so it will be
         * in memory (mallocated) the moment you tell it to be something.
         */
        if (!delObj) {
```

In this case, we want that static object to be an instance of Delegate (not a particularly good name to set your class to, it will lead to much confusion). We "start" or initialize this class by calling `init` and we tell it this is an object we need, chuck it on the **heap** [read this](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-01-15-stack-and-heap-objects-in-objective-c.html).

```
        delObj = [[Delegate alloc] init];
    }

    // Now we can call the function in the next file
    [delObj helloWorld];
}
```

`Delegate.m` - Think of this as a different file. You can access this file from `extern.c` because (in reality) it's just included in the same file. But this of this as a separate entity entirely. You have to access this "*file*" from `extern.c`

```
@implementation Delegate

// This is the function we call with [[Delegate alloc] init];
-(id) init {
    // It simply returns itself - saying hey this is the object memory chunk in the heap you want to talk to.
    return self;
}

// This is the function we call with [delObj helloWorld];
- (void) helloWorld {
    NSLog("Hello World"); // This will show up in your console.
}
```

So the above code has two functions, one that says "this is the memory object your looking for" - one that says "I'm a function, lets execute something".

Now with all that laid out, you're not calling:

```
-(void) alertView: (UIAlertView*)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

**OR**

```
-(void)SMS:(id)sender{
```

Via your `extern "C"`. The reason why `_AddNotification` works is because you have code in there calling `UIAlertView` ***AFTER*** making sure your `delegateObject` is in memory. In you `_SMSGO` function, you're not putting your object into memory. So when you call `delegateObject` in `[delegateObject presentViewController:controller animated:YES];` it says "Oh I know what `delegateObject` *is* but it's equal to nothing. In fact it does not have memory to execute anything!" Thats why you probably don't get any errors or exceptions. The code knows there is a static object, but it hasn't been set to anything yet.

**SOLUTION:**

First, void methods don't need `:(id)sender` thats more of a `IBAction` thing unless you actually want to send something - so change `-(void)SMS:(id)sender{` to `- (void) SMS {` (with the pretty spacing, too. It's *mo' better* for eyes).

Second, swap everything in `SMS` with:

```
- (void) SMS {

    MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [controller setMessageComposeDelegate:self];

    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]){

        [controller setRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:nil]];
        [controller setBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Text"]];

        // We now know why we work!
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }    
}
```

But WAIT! And *do not* copy and paste. Be sure to understand each line of code you write.

This line **allocates** an object into memory, in this instance, the `MFMessageComposeViewController` object. Then initializes it.

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
```

This line sets the **delegate** of the object we just made (`controller`). But ***why*** can it do this? Because we have `MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate` set in the `iOSBridge.h` file. This tells everything in your `.mm` file "hey if we happen to have a `MFMessage` object somewhere, it *may* access delegate properties if you want."
`[controller setMessageComposeDelegate:self];`

`if ( [MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText] )` is human readable.

Same with `[controller setRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:nil]];` and `[controller setBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Text"]];`

But now `[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES];` is were we need to dive in.

So in Unity, they said "hey, we don't need to deal with every single possible native function being called" - so they created access to the `extern` capability for you. This allows you to talk to Objective-C from the UnityScript side of things. Objective-C is just a superset of C, so thats common ground. Everything in here should ONLY call functions *in* `Delegate`. The example of this is above in the fake `extern.c` code block. The only thing that is doing is creating `delegateObject` and calling a function. Now for the next step. Swap everything in `_SMSGO` with:

```
void _SMSGO (const char *mBody) { // I prefer char *name vs char* name but it doesn't matter

    [delegateObject SMS]; // add mBody as a parameter when you're ready. Handle the stringWithUTF8String on the Objective-C side of things. Yes, this is not the Obj-C side, this is the C side.

}
```

"But wait... you just `delegateObject` needs to be a *thing*" - Yes it does. Create another method in your `extern "C"` section called `_init` and run this **one time** from Unity in the `Awake` or `Start` function of your class. This will set your static object one time and never mess with it again. Simply make it:

```
void _init() {
    if ( !delegateObject ) {
        delegateObject = [[Delegate alloc] init];
    }
}
```

`!delegateObject` is the same thing as `delegateObject == nil` but cleaner code. Both say "We don't know what dat is" - Ok now we have our `delegateObject`, we are free to make our next calls with `delegateObject` as much as we'd like.

Now when you call `[delegateObject SMS]` it goes to `- (void) SMS`. And when you call `self presentViewController` it knows that self is referring to an ***iOS Native Object***. If you call `presentViewController` in `extern "C"` it says "... um, hmm. I haven't got the foggiest notion what that means" - for this reason, we have use **everything** in your `extern "C"` section as a crossover to your `Delegate` object. That is the whole purpose of the `extern` thing, just to call things in your Obj-C stuff.

Hope this helps.